# Show $\mathcal D_D$ is Dynkin system

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal D\subset\mathcal P(\Omega)$ be a Dynkin system and $D\in\mathcal D$. Then $\mathcal D_D=\{A\subset\Omega|A\cap D\in\mathcal D\}$ is a Dynkin system.

It's clear that $\Omega\in\mathcal D_D$. But I'm not sure how to show that

i) for $A\in\mathcal D_D$ we also have $A^C\in\mathcal D_D$

ii) for $A_1,...\in\mathcal D_D$ with $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$ we also have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in\mathcal D_D$

For ii) I was thinking that if $(A_i)$ is a sequence in $\mathcal D_D$ we have $A_i\cap D\in\mathcal D$ for all $i$. So we have $\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)\cap D = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \underbrace{A_i\cap D}_{\in \mathcal D}$. But can I argue that this union  is also in $\mathcal D$?

And how do I show i)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (ii): Yes, you can argue like this, note that 
$$(A_i \cap D)  \cap (A_j \cap D) = (A_i \cap A_j) \cap D = \emptyset ,\quad i \ne j $$
by assumption on the $A_i$. Now use that $\mathcal D$ is a Dynkin system.

For (i): Suppose $A \cap D \in \mathcal D$, we have 
$$ A^c \cap D = (A \cup D^c)^c = \bigl( (A\cap D) \cup D^c \bigr)^c $$
Now use that $D \in \mathcal D$, that $A\cap D$ and $D^c$ are disjoint and $\mathcal D$ is a Dynkin system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first one is really easy if you know how to rewrite the intersection of $A^c$ and $D$. I'm not quite sure about the second one, though. From what I understand we have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty A_i\cap D = \emptyset$ due to the fact that the sets are disjoint. And since $\Omega\in\mathcal D$ and $\mathcal D$ is a Dynkin system we get $\emptyset\in\mathcal D$ and hence ii)?